# How to animate a button on show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a button to fadeInDown when it appears after scrolling 20 px down, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

I have fadeInDown in my .css file, but I can't find where to call it (either in javascript or in .html)

```js
  window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollFunction()
  };

  function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
      document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "block";
      $('#topBtn').fadeInDown('slow');
    } else {
      document.getElementById("topBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
  function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
  }
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -o-transform: translatey(-10px);
    transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
    -moz-transform: translatey(0);
    -o-transform: translatey(0);
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -o-transform: translatey(-10px);
    transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
    -moz-transform: translatey(0);
    -o-transform: translatey(0);
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translatey(-10px);
    -o-transform: translatey(-10px);
    transform: translatey(-10px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
    -moz-transform: translatey(0);
    -o-transform: translatey(0);
    transform: translatey(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onShow="animation: fadeInDown" class="animated fadeInDown" onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
```

Expected the button to be animated when it shows, but it just pops in to existence.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery yet? It has many cool features for animating elements.

Comment: @AlirezaA2F It looks like they have: `$('#topBtn').fadeIn('slow');` ...

Comment: `onshow` event is only for notifications, it is not fired when you set a display style. Also `animation: fadeInDown` in an inline event handler does nothing.

Comment: You can use Javascript libraries to do that. anime.js is very powerfull https://animejs.com/, Bounce.js is another option

Comment: There is no method called `fadeInDown` in jQuery -> `$('#topBtn').fadeInDown('slow')`. Instead, you need to add the class `fadeInDown` when you want the button to animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can actually be done very easily with jQuery UI like so:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrollPosition > 20) {
    $('#scroll-to-top').show("drop",{direction: "up"},300);
  } else {
    $('#scroll-to-top').hide("drop",{direction: "up"},300);
  }
});
```

```css
.scroll-to-top {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:24px;
  right:24px;
}
.content {
  height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="scroll-to-top" class="scroll-to-top">
  Scroll To Top
</button>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Let me know if this worked. See the code snippet for the example.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `onshow` to achieve this. Simply add the animation as a style property to your button and it will automatically trigger when display is set to block.

```
#topBtn {
  position: fixed;
  animation: fadeInDown 500ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

Add this in your style, because you have not defined `animated` class in your style